# Why didn't Voyager use fluidic space to get home?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

In the Voyager episode "Scorpion" (S03E26-S04E01), Voyager entered fluidic space, where species 8472 lives. In Unimatrix Zero, Axum mentions an entry into fluidic space in the Beta Quadrant. Surely Voyager could have found a way to exit fluidic space somewhere else further from the Borg and closer to Earth, so why didn't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would likely result in Voyager's almost immediate destruction.

The last time we see Species 8472, they've become paranoid about an invasion from Earth. They're setting up facilities to assist with the infiltration of and, one assumes, the destruction of the Federation. Although Janeway convinces a small group to not attack (and to conduct limited diplomatic overtures) that's a big difference between turning up in their space and zooming around.

> **JANEWAY:** *Thank you, but the real Earth is a long way from here. I'd like to get back on the road. What are the chances they'll listen to you?*
>
> **BOOTHBY/8472:** *I can't promise you the moon, Captain. My superiors aren't as forward thinking. Peace with humans? Wow. They're going to hit the roof. But I'll tell them what happened here today, and with a pinch of luck a few of them might see the light.*
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: In the Flesh](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/504.htm)</sup></sub>

Additionally, fluidic space can't be traveled at warp speeds. We see in the game [ST: Armada II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Armada_II) that you're restricted to a relatively low sublight speed and in [Star Trek: Alien Domain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Alien_Domain) we learn that most FTL travel in fluidic space is conducted using subspace vacuoles and wormholes, all of which are controlled by Species 8472.

Comment: I'd love to see The Think Tank get sent to fluidic space by Q. I wonder how it would fare.